# MySQL select two smallest id with duplicated conditions

Tags: mysql

So i have a table room like this

```
+---------+-------------+
| room_id | status      |
+---------+-------------+
| 1       | unavailable |
| 2       | available   |
| 3       | unavailable |
| 4       | available   |
| 5       | available   |
+---------+-------------+
```

if I use

```
SELECT * FROM room WHERE status='available'
```

the output of course will be

```
+---------+-----------+
| room_id | status    |
+---------+-----------+
| 2       | available |
| 4       | available |
| 5       | available |
+---------+-----------+
```

But i want the output only two of the smallest id like this

```
+---------+-----------+
| room_id | status    |
+---------+-----------+
| 2       | available |
| 4       | available |
+---------+-----------+
```

Can you guys help me with this?thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - using order by and limit

```
SELECT * FROM room WHERE status='available'
order by room_id asc
limit 2
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works. And sorry for this basic question, this is my firs db :D